# Android. Разметка. Как сделать layout по ширине карточки

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Что то туплю на ровном месте, не понимаю как выровнять layout с полупрозрачным фоном по ширине итема RecyclerView, использую GridLayoutmanager

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<xyz.rnovoselov.photon.photon.ui.custom_views.AspectRatioImageView
    android:id="@+id/photocard_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:aspect_ratio="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal_8"
    android:background="@color/text_shadow_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favorite_txt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_little_8"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_custom_favorites_white_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_16"
        android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_regular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_small_12"
        tools:text="90" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/views_txt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_little_8"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_custom_views_white_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_16"
        android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_regular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_small_12"
        tools:text="90" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayout это и есть та самая штука которую необходимо растянуть

Update:
Поправил разметку: у картинки тоже поставил ширину match_parent

```
<xyz.rnovoselov.photon.photon.ui.custom_views.AspectRatioImageView
    android:id="@+id/photocard_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:aspect_ratio="1" />
```

LinearLayout стал по ширине карточки, однако при пролистывании RecyclerView карточки при биндинге изменяют свой размер, как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А пробовали у корневого фрейм лейаута `android:layout_width="match_parent"` и первоначальный вариант всего остального?

Comment: Да, это помогло, только что хотел обновить вопрос, спасибо.